# building QTCharts by using cmake

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cmake

I'm currently working on a project where Qt5Charts is used in a linux platform. By default there was qt5.5 in the system. I have installed qt5.8 in my home directory.

To build the project I'm using cmake. My Cmakefile looks something like this

```
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
    if(Qt5Widgets_FOUND)
        set( QT_INCLUDE_DIR
            ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        )
        include_directories( ${QT_INCLUDE_DIR} )
        set (LIBS ${LIBS} ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES} )
    endif()

find_package(Qt5Charts)
    if(Qt5Charts_FOUND)
        set( QT_INCLUDE_DIR
            ${Qt5Charts_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        )
        include_directories( ${QT_INCLUDE_DIR} )
        set (LIBS ${LIBS} ${Qt5Charts_LIBRARIES} )
    endif()
```

But the cmake is not been able to find Qt5Charts as it is only available in Qt5.8. The Qt5Widgets is successfully found as it is available in Qt5.5 also.

For Qt5Charts it says

> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Charts" with
>     any of the following names:    Qt5ChartsConfig.cmake
>       qt5charts-config.cmake

Is there a way that I tell cmake to look for packages of Qt5.8 instead of Qt5.5? Or is there a way to specify the default path to look for?

> Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib/cmake is the location of cmakeFiles for 5.8
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake for 5.5

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed Qt with `apt-get` or `yum` or `dnf` or any other package manager, you need to install `Charts` separately. I was experiencing the same in Fedora with Qt 5.8. Installation of `qt5-qtcharts-devel` solved the issue.

```
sudo dnf install qt5-qtcharts-devel
```

for debian based distributions and other distributions the package name may be different.

However In my Mac I've installed qt5 using `brew` there it installed everything including `charts`.

Comment: That would be `sudo apt install libqt5charts5-dev` for Debian / Ubuntu based distibutions.