# CMake file cannot locate Qt charts module

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cmake, clion

I'm trying to start writing my Qt project inside JetBrains' Clion but I need to link some libraries in my Cmake file first. There's no problem when trying to find packages like Qt5Core, Qt5Widgets, Qt5Gui but when it come to finding Qt5Charts an error is thrown:

> > By not providing "FindQt5Charts.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project   has asked CMake to find a package configuration file
> >     provided by   "Qt5Charts", but CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Charts"
>   with   any of the following names:
>
> ```
> Qt5ChartsConfig.cmake
> qt5charts-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Charts" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
>   set   "Qt5Charts_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
>   files.  If   "Qt5Charts" provides a separate development package or
>   SDK, be sure it has   been installed.

[This is my CMake file right now.](https://pastebin.com/ZbRJtLT2)

All packages are installed via the Qt's Linux(ubuntu) maintanence tool.
Any ideas how to help Cmake find the Charts module ?

Comment: Some Qt 5.x versions had problems with including QtCharts, and one of the keywords to solve was `QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE`...

Comment: @Vladimir Bershov Where do you type those keywords? In the Cmake?

Comment: Did you add `QT += charts` to your `.pro` file ?

Comment: @VladimirBershov yes I did.

Answer (score 4):

Using the following and see if it helps:

> sudo apt install libqt5charts5-dev

Src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46765025

Answer (score 1):

Typically when including Qt5 in a project I use the follow basic script for CMake, though I should note I haven't tested this on Linux.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets Charts)

# set your project sources and headers
set(project_sources src/blah.cpp)
set(project_headers include/headers/blah.h)

# wrap your qt based classes with qmoc
qt5_wrap_cpp(project_source_moc ${project_headers})

# add your build target
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${project_sources} ${project_headers} ${project_source_moc})

# link to Qt5
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Gui
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Charts)

# require C++ 14
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_14)
```

When configuring your project via cmake, you just need to pass in the path to you qt5 installation directory (cmake variable name is `Qt5_DIR`) that contains the `Qt5Config.cmake` file and then cmake should be able to find the rest of the components that you request.

Also double check that `Qt5Charts` was installed, not sure if it's installed by default.

Comment: same CMake Error thrown:
`By not providing "FindQt5Charts.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Charts", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Charts" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5ChartsConfig.cmake
    qt5charts-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Charts" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Charts_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Charts" provides a separate development package or SDK....`

Comment: @StoyanLupov have you double checked that Qt5Charts is in fact installed? Does it exist in your Qt5 install directory?

Comment: yes, I've installed everything from their "Maintanence tool". QtCharts included

Comment: @StoyanLupov Are Widgets, Core, and Gui automatically found successfully?

Comment: yes, they are. No problems finding them using find_package

Comment: @StoyanLupov you mean with `find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets Charts)` right? Not the way you were doing it? Under your `<qt5 install directory>/lib/cmake` is there a folder for Qt5Charts? (Not sure if it's structured like that for linux?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167179/discussion-between-developer-paul-and-stoyan-lupov).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
sudo apt install libqt5charts5-dev
```